# How do I accept only numbers and reject letters for input tel

Tags: html, input, input-type-file

Despite my constant research, I have seen studies that accept letters for input tel.

```html
<input
  type="tel"
  placeholder="Phone Number"
  required
  pattern="^[0-9-+\s()]*$"
  maxLength="16"
  minLength="6"
  data-for="phoneNumber"
/>
```

Here I want it to only accept numbers. But it also accepts letters. How can I fix this?

Comment: [Read MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/tel)

Answer (score 2):

The design team at the UK Government did a bunch of research and concluded that [you shouldn't try to prevent that](https://technology.blog.gov.uk/2020/02/24/why-the-gov-uk-design-system-team-changed-the-input-type-for-numbers/)

> The web and Android versions of Chrome implement this by silently discarding all letter input except the letter ‘e’.
>
> This means users are not given feedback on what type of characters `<input type="number">` accepts, and assistive technologies don’t alert the user that their input has been silently discarded.

According to them, your best bet would be to just use `<input type="tel">` and validate server-side to make sure that letters aren't included.

*Edit: although the link references `<input type="number">` which you haven't asked about, my understanding of your request is that you're trying to prevent people entering certain characters into your input field, which `<input type="number">` does, and the advise is: don't try.*

Answer (score 0):

Use input : number instead

```html
<input type="number">
```

This will only accept number

Comment: why is someone downwoting this answer????  His answer is as incorrect as above mentioned and accepted answer. What a world we are leaving in

Answer (score 0):

Why not trying following regular expression **REGEX**, since it will also fit your **length** requirement:

```html
<input
  type="tel"
  placeholder="Phone Number"
  required
  pattern="^[0-9-+\s()]{6,16}"
  data-for="phoneNumber"
/>
```